# Why does a cout statement at the beginning of my program not output anything?

Tags: c++

So I'm working on some code for a class. Yes I know the input validation I'm trying to work out is inefficient and the program is unfinished. I don't need the rest of it to work. Here's the code.

```
/*Write a program that allows the user to enter a payroll code.
 The program should search for the payroll code in the file and then display the appropriate salary.
 If the payroll code is not in the file, the program should display an appropriate message.
 Use a sentinel value to end the program.*/

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;


int main(){
    int code;
    ifstream PayrollFile;
    int FCode;
    int Salary;
    char Trash;
    string line;
    string lineTwo;
    int NumOfCodes=0;
    int Subscript=0;

    cout << "everything is starting";

    PayrollFile.open("/Users/fnord/Desktop/Payroll.txt");

    do{
        lineTwo=line;
        PayrollFile >> line;
        NumOfCodes++;
    }
    while (line!=lineTwo);

    PayrollFile.close();
    PayrollFile.open("/Users/fnord/Desktop/Payroll.txt");

    int ListOfPayrollCodes[NumOfCodes-1];

    while (Subscript<NumOfCodes){
        while (PayrollFile >> FCode >> Trash >> Salary) {
            cout << FCode;
            ListOfPayrollCodes[Subscript]=FCode;
            Subscript++;
        }
    }

    PayrollFile.close();
    PayrollFile.open("/Users/fnord/Desktop/Payroll.txt");

    cout << "please enter the payroll code";
    cin >> code;

    while (PayrollFile >> FCode >> Trash >> Salary) {
        if (code==FCode) {
            cout << "The salary is " << Salary << endl;
        }
    }
    PayrollFile.close();
}
```

The thing I'm confused about is the fact that the compiler never seems to reach this line:

```
cout << "everything is starting";
```

As far as I can tell, there is nothing before this line that should stop the program from outputting "everything is starting" but "everything is starting" never shows up in the output. 
The code builds and begins running but never stops and fails to output anything. My teacher couldn't figure this out either.

I'm running OSX10.9 and using XCode for my compiler. I've tried other compilers with the same results.

Thanks!

Comment: Line. Buffering. You forgot to flush.

Comment: Try `cout << "everything is starting" << endl;` or `cout << "everything is starting"; cout.flush();`

Comment: If you can execute the program, then your compiler has most definitely reached the line in question. It couldn't have completed the translation if it hadn't reached that line. Stop accusing the compiler of doing things wrong. It's Not The Compiler.

Comment: XCode isn't a compiler.

Comment: To be sure if you reach this line or not, inspect your program using a debugger, and step through line by line.

Comment: @KerrekSB, Should it not be flushed automatically when `cin >> code;` is executed? I don't see anything in particular that would result in an infinite loop before then.

Comment: @chris: "using (a version of) XCode (compatible with and configured) for my compiler" would be correct... but almost certainly not what OP was thinking.

Comment: @chris: It would be flushed, it it reached the `cin` usage.  But there's a (probably infinite) loop in between.

Comment: Oh, I missed the nested `while`s. That might do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In these loops:

```
while (Subscript<NumOfCodes){
    while (PayrollFile >> FCode >> Trash >> Salary) {
        cout << FCode;
        ListOfPayrollCodes[Subscript]=FCode;
        Subscript++;
    }
}
```

If extraction fails, `PayrollFile` starts converting to `false`, and there's no longer any way for `Subscript` to increase.  So the outer loop never terminates.

Instead use:

```
while ((Subscript<NumOfCodes) && (PayrollFile >> FCode >> Trash >> Salary)) {
    cout << FCode;
    ListOfPayrollCodes[Subscript]=FCode;
    Subscript++;
}
```

For your printf-debugging needs, when using `cout`, also use `std::flush` or `std::endl`.  Otherwise the output will be buffered, and not help you learn where your program got stuck.  (For actually writing out large quantities of data, you'll want to avoid flushing any more than necessary, because it kills performance.)

Comment: Also, pre-C++11 `open()` doesn't clear `failbit`, so it's an almost guaranteed infinite loop...

Answer (score 1):

Use breakpoints. when you started to debug check if they are still red or turned white. if turned white you can see a note there about the situation. if its red and you cant reach it means its never getting there.

Answer (score 0):

*cout* is a **buffered stream**; to force the output you should

- using *endl* manipulator;
- usinf *flush()* method

Comment: It should suffice to just have a newline in the string, since the stream is typically line buffered.

Comment: if you means '\n' the answer in NO.

Answer (score 0):

int ListOfPayrollCodes[NumOfCodes-1]; - // This line should not compile.You're using a variable to declare the size of an array . This is supposed to be a constant.

I'm not sure how you compile this code. Please fix a constant and see, how it sounds. I hardcoded it and commented the Numcodes increment line and I could print it.

Update: Ok, Looks like you're saying the compiler does not reach this line. That means, the code does not compile. The reason is above.

I understand that you want an array of size ListOfPayrollCodes. Use dynamic allocation as opposed to static allocation, it will work fine.